# Slow slime after abortion

Tags: slime

If I happen to execute an infinite loop and abort with `C-c C-b`, SLIME is unbearably slow after that, and I have to restart EMACS.  Why is that, and can I do anything other than restart?

Comment: Award for most disturbing post title of the day.